# Sketch a function in the interval [-2,3] that has the following characteristics

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

> Sketch a function in the interval [-2,3] that has the following characteristics:[image]

Here is what I got:

[image]

**Is this correct?**

Comment: That looks correct to me.

Comment: Nice job.  Two minor quibbles.  If $f'(x) = 3$ in the interval $(-1, 0)$, the graph should be the line segment connecting the point $(-1, 0)$ with $(0, 3)$.  If that is what you intended, it is not clear from your graph.  Also, your graph should stop when $x = 3$.